# Angular2 - Share component controllers

Tags: javascript, angular, controller, components

I have two page components that use the same methods with the exception of using two different type classes. The two components are called Services and Users. Both components use templates that are very similar with the exception of the class property info it displays. It seems to be inefficient to repeat methods on both controllers, is there a way to combine/share controllers.

Services.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common'; 
const template = require('./service.component.html');
const style = require('./service.component.css'); 

interface Service {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    summary: string;
    path: string; 
}; 

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-services',
  directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  template: template,
  styles: [ style ]
})

export class ServiceComponent {
  services = Services; 
  selectedService:Service ; 
  constructor() {
  }

  onselect(service:Service){
    this.selectedService = service ; 
  }
  onEdit(service:Service){
    console.log("Edit: "+service); 
  }
  onDelete(service:Service){
      console.log("Delete: "+service);
  }
  onView(service:Service){
    console.log("View: "+service); 
  }
  onAdd(){
    this.selectedService = <Service>{}; 
  }
}
```

User.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common'; 
const template = require('./users.component.html');
const style = require('./users.component.css'); 

interface User {
    id: number;
    image: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    role: string; 
}; 

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-users',
  directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  template: template,
  styles: [ style ]
})

export class UsersComponent {
  users = Users; 
  selectedUser:User ; 
  constructor() {
  }

  onselect(user:User){
    this.selectedUser = user ; 
  }
  onEdit(user:User){
    console.log("Edit: "+user); 
  }
  onDelete(user:User){
      console.log("Delete: "+user);
  }
  onView(user:User){
    console.log("View: "+user); 
  }
  onAdd(){
    this.selectedUser = <User>{}; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this is where Angular's component-driven design and Typescripts's class-driven design really shine:

Having defined a `ServicesComponent` as you have above, you can simply extend that class and attach different component metadata to it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-users',
  directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  template: template,
  styles: [ style ]
})
export class UsersComponent extends ServicesComponent { 
    constructor(){
      super();
    } 

    //override whatever methods/fields in the parent class you need to (and only those)


}
```

Comment: Then i have to make the methods in a servic, and then make them again in my user controller.

Comment: In the above example, the `UsersComponent` controller class will inherit all the methods on the `ServicesComponent` class it extends, they don't have to be reimplemented.

Comment: I get this error. Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call.

Comment: Cool thanks. This works with non components to right, so I can have a super class without any of the angular2 component properties?

Comment: Yes, inheritance is just Typescript, it has nothing to do with angular :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a service with a single set of methods and pass in an object.  Then cast the object to the desired class and use it in the method.

Comment: Then i have to make the methods in a service, and then make them again in my controllers.